# C/C++ string shift to a specific element - least possible steps

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, c-strings

here's my dilema.

I have for example this string:

"1 2 3 4 5 .....  100" , but it can be any length (usually much, much bigger one, talking about 4 digit numbers).

What I need to do: re-arrange the elements of the string based on a known possition. 
E.g: the position in question is 70. I need to have the following output:
"70 71 ....100 1 2 3 ...69"

Conditions:

1. I know the key: e.g the above "70". Can be also 500, 5000, depends on the string length.
2. I can't use any string buffers or string management functions.
3. There's little to none memory available.
4. There are two 1 byte buffers available.
5. Operation should be done in with the least possible steps (time critical).

I've been trying to find a good algorithm that would not depend on the position of key in the string. Basically shifting left/right depending on what half I am still makes it for a lot of reads/writes and I don't want that.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: when you say "position 70" do you mean the 70th char, or literally the position of the sub string "70"?

Comment: Also, are the number sub-strings guaranteed to be sorted? If so, the char index of the a given numeric string can be calculated easily...

Comment: when I mean "70" I mean the position 70 and not the numeric value. Can be any kind of data byte at that position.

Comment: and no, it's not homework, it's something I've run into at work (working on old school embedded systems)

Comment: well is the data at position 70 a single byte big though? "70" is two bytes, "700" is 3 bytes...

Comment: Your 2 byte buffer is just enough to store an arbitrary index to your string. How many working registers do you have and how wide are they?

Comment: Looks like pancake-flipping to me. I guess it could be done with three reversals (one whole reversal, and two for the two halves)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code fits your decription, but you've been vague enough that I doubt it does what you want...

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cassert>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    int n = 15;
    std::string s = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20  ";

    uint16_t index;
    switch((int)log10(n)) {
    case 0: // 0 - 9 
        // -2 to account for lack of "0" in the list which would have occupied 2 chars..
        index = (2 * (n)) + -2;
        break;
    case 1: // 10 - 99
        index = (3 * (n % 10)) + (10 * 2 - 2);
        break;
    case 2: // 100 - 999
        index = (4 * (n % 100)) + (90 * 3) + (10 * 2 - 2);
        break;
    case 3: // 1000 - 9999
        index = (5 * (n % 1000)) + (900 * 4) + (90 * 3) + (10 * 2 - 2);
        break;
    }

    std::string::iterator first  = s.begin();
    std::string::iterator middle = s.begin() + index;
    std::string::iterator last   = s.end();

    std::string::iterator next = middle;
    while(first != next) {

        char temp1;
        temp1 = *first;
        *first = *next;
        *next = temp1;

        ++first;
        ++next;

        if (next == last) {
            next = middle;
        } else if (first == middle) {
            middle = next;
        }
    }

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
$ ./test 
15 16 17 18 19 20 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```

But should work just the same for sequences all the way up to `9999`

Comment: that's it! tyvm. Might need to optimize it a bit for large strings but yeah, that's pretty much what I was looking for

Comment: keep in mind, this only works if the initial string is sorted because i do some math to calculate the offset of a given digit. This math assumes that the numbers are in order and have no gaps.. Also, if you feel this is the correct answer. Feel free to up-vote it ;-).

Comment: I need 15 rep to upvote, but yeah, I accepted the answer (i guess). First time here -.-

Answer (score 4):

```
std::vector<std::string> numbers((std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin)),
                                 std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
std::rotate(numbers.begin(), numbers.begin() + 70, numbers.end());
```

Comment: isn't that = (key * length) rotations? I'm looking for something that doesn't factor in the key.

Comment: @totococo: `std::rotate` is linear and does, at most, `last-first` swaps. The answer you accepted simply reinvents what `std::rotate` already does.

Comment: Agreed, the only major difference between this answer and mine is that this one slurps the numbers into a `vector` and works with that, mine works directly with the source character array. The actual rotation is identical.

Answer (score 2):

This is the 3*reverse method I mentioned in the comments. Just plain C, no fancy string classes. Needs only one element of storage for the swap.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int array[] = { 0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} ;
#define COUNT (sizeof array / sizeof array[0])

void reverse(int *arr, size_t siz);
void doprint(int *arr, size_t siz);
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
unsigned pos = 3;

if (argc >1 && argv[1]) sscanf(argv[1], "%u", &pos);
if (pos >= COUNT) exit(1);

doprint(array, COUNT);
reverse(array,COUNT);
reverse(array,pos);
reverse(array+pos,COUNT-pos);
doprint(array, COUNT);
return 0;
}

void doprint(int *arr, size_t siz)
{
while( siz--) {
        printf(" %d", *arr++);
        }
printf("\n");
}

void reverse(int *arr, size_t siz)
{
int * end;
for (end= arr+siz-1; end > arr; end--,arr++) {
        int tmp;
        tmp = *arr;
        *arr = *end;
        *end = tmp;
        }
}
```

For those who don't believe, here is the result:

```
$ ./a.out 3
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: does this **reverse** the array? If so, you've misunderstood the question. He wants to **rotate** the array: For example: `"1 2 3 4 5"` to become `"3 4 5 1 2"`...

Comment: Yes it does. (You could try compile and run the program) I'll post the results.

Comment: oh, i get it, you reverse the whole thing, then split it around a mid-point and reverse the two individually, resulting in a "rotation", nice. Although his request was for a string, which makes it a little more complex than with straight up integers.

Comment: I beg to differ. It is *not* more difficult for a string.

Comment: I didn't say, "difficult", i said "complex". Certainly there is the extra work of figuring out the byte offset of pivot point with a string which is not present with a plain old array of `int`s.

Comment: No need to figure that out, he wants the raw offset. See the OP's first comment on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement this yourself from scratch, the clue is that by swapping pairs of bytes you can arrange to move a section of the string into the right place (either the start or the end as appropriate), leaving you a shorter length of string which still needs to be rotated into place. Eventually you will run out of string to rotate.

Comment: that would still factor in the key with the number of shifts, and that is what I was trying to avoid. Evan gave me the answer, thanks!

Comment: @totococo My answer should at least help you understand why his answer works, after all, it does work by swapping bytes.